# OpenCV ANDROID_ABI: not all variants are displayed

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.13 release from [GitHub](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.13). Then I configured CMake project using CMake-gui for android.

There is variable called ANDROID_ABI and I can select value for it using drop-down list. But in this list I can chose only armeabi, armeabi-v6 with VFP, armeabi-v7a, armeabi-v7a with NEON, armeabi-v7a with VFPV3.

I can use CMake console for configure and generate project for arm64 or I can modify cmake scripts and list it manually. But when I try to build generated project, I get error `unknown type name '__uint128_t'__uint128_t`. So I think there are reasons why I can't select this variant from drop-down list.

How can I chose arm64 variant for build and why I get such kind of error?

Comment: Same problem for `opencv 4.0.1`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your toolchain, has no armv8 64 bit option. 
However there is an new opencv 3.0 release, and probably your uint errors will be fixed:

http://opencv.org/downloads.html

If your toolchain doesn't support 64 bits, you can make your own toolchain for arm64.

```
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh \
--arch=arm --platform=android-21 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html?hl=es

Don't forget to put android_native_level in 21 (android 5.0.1) on cmake android options, because 64 bit support is done on devices which have android 5 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I can use OpenCV 3.1 now, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong. If I can build arm64 .so file with precompiled OpenCV using NDK, does it mean that I have arm64 toolchain? For now I have other problem. Somehow I changed cmake target platform to arm64 and now I build OpenCV 2.4.13 arm64 without problems, but I don't know how switch it back to arm platform )=.

Comment: Using default toolchain in cmake, you will have armeabi and armv7 (diferent versions), so, you can choose your preferred toolchain. 

Check this link https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake/blob/master/android.toolchain.cmake, there is android default toolchain.  Cheers.

Comment: Is there any method for windows? It seems that it is a sh file dedicated on linux...

Comment: yeah is true, sh files are for linux, however there should be python scripts that they make the same process and they should work in windows.
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
        --arch arm --api 21 --install-dir /tmp/my-android-toolchain
    If you have problems making standalone toolchain, you can install mingw linux shell for windows to overcome the issues.